# Why does this 'else' return an error?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm creating an program for my Graduation exercise and I'm stuck with the `Else Error`.

When I set off the line marked with `#` no problem appears.
I'm currently using [repl.it](https://repl.it/) to program it and that's the code below
Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 45
    else:
   ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
                 #3° exercicio
'''
Escreva um programa que pergunte a quantidade de KM percorridos
por um carro alugado pelo
usuário, assim como a quantidade de dias pelos quais o carro
foi alugado.
Calcule o preço a pagar , sabendo que o carro custa
R$:60,00 por dia e R$ 0,15 por km rodado
'''

print ("Olá, bem vindo a RENT A NAVE; Qual carro você gostaria ?")
print("Pressione enter para ver as opções ")
input()
print ("Pressione as teclas correspondentes")
print ('Digite p3008 para  Peugeot 3008')
print ('Digite kcadenza  para Kia Cadenza')
print ('Digite tprius para Toyota Prius')
print ('Digite f124 para Fiat 124 Spider')
menu_voltar = str("Verifique a lista de opções, opção digitada incorreta")
p3008 = str("p3008")
f124 = str("f124") 
kcadenza = str ("kcadenza")
tprius = str("tprius")
valor_peugeot  = str('Sua escolha custa R$:60,00 por dia e R$ 0,15 por km rodado')
valor_tprius = str('Sua escolha custa R$:60,00 por dia e R$ 0,15 por km rodado ')
valor_kcadenza = str('Sua escolha custa R$:60,00 por dia e R$ 0,15 por km rodado ')
valorf124 =   str('Sua escolha custa R$:60,00 por dia e R$ 0,15 por km rodado ')
user_information1 = str (input("Qual a sua opção"))
valor_total_dia = 60
valor_total_km = 0.15

if user_information1 == p3008  :
   print ('Parabens vc escolheu um Peugeot 3008 ')
   print ('Sua escolha custa R$:60,00 por dia e R$ 0,15 por km rodado')

   carro_km = int (input("Você sabe uma média em Km que ira rodar  com o carro ? "))
   carro_dias = int (input("Quantos Dias você vai usar o carro ?"))
   user_information1 = int(carro_km * valor_total_km) 
   user_information2 = int (carro_dias  * valor_total_dia)

print ('O Valor a pagar em um total de KMs é :','R$',user_information1 ,',00' ' e o seu valor a pagar por dias com o carro é : R$', user_information2 ,',00')

'''
 ########### this line below gimme the error ##### why ? 
else:
  print (menu_voltar)
  '''
```

Would you please help me to understand why is this so?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Because `print` is not in the `if` statement anymore. So the `else` can't match any `if`

Comment: You don't need `str(...)` around `input` -- they are already strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an incorrect indent and the `else` tag couldn't match any `if` so the `SyntaxError` occurred. Modify the `print` statement to be inside the `if` blocks indentation level.  Hope this will help you

```
'''
Escreva um programa que pergunte a quantidade de KM percorridos
por um carro alugado pelo
usuário, assim como a quantidade de dias pelos quais o carro
foi alugado.
Calcule o preço a pagar , sabendo que o carro custa
R$:60,00 por dia e R$ 0,15 por km rodado
'''

print ("Olá, bem vindo a RENT A NAVE; Qual carro você gostaria ?")
print("Pressione enter para ver as opções ")
input()
print ("Pressione as teclas correspondentes")
print ('Digite p3008 para  Peugeot 3008')
print ('Digite kcadenza  para Kia Cadenza')
print ('Digite tprius para Toyota Prius')
print ('Digite f124 para Fiat 124 Spider')
menu_voltar = str("Verifique a lista de opções, opção digitada incorreta")
p3008 = str("p3008")
f124 = str("f124") 
kcadenza = str ("kcadenza")
tprius = str("tprius")
valor_peugeot  = str('Sua escolha custa R$:60,00 por dia e R$ 0,15 por km rodado')
valor_tprius = str('Sua escolha custa R$:60,00 por dia e R$ 0,15 por km rodado ')
valor_kcadenza = str('Sua escolha custa R$:60,00 por dia e R$ 0,15 por km rodado ')
valorf124 =   str('Sua escolha custa R$:60,00 por dia e R$ 0,15 por km rodado ')
user_information1 = str (input("Qual a sua opção"))
valor_total_dia = 60
valor_total_km = 0.15

if user_information1 == p3008  :
   print ('Parabens vc escolheu um Peugeot 3008 ')
   print ('Sua escolha custa R$:60,00 por dia e R$ 0,15 por km rodado')

   carro_km = int (input("Você sabe uma média em Km que ira rodar  com o carro ? "))
   carro_dias = int (input("Quantos Dias você vai usar o carro ?"))
   user_information1 = int(carro_km * valor_total_km) 
   user_information2 = int (carro_dias  * valor_total_dia)

   print ('O Valor a pagar em um total de KMs é :','R$',user_information1 ,',00' ' e o seu valor a pagar por dias com o carro é : R$', user_information2 ,',00')

else:
  print (menu_voltar)
```

Comment: I'll try in a bit and let you know guys ! thx a lot meanwhile

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are separating the if and else conditions with a `print()`.

In detail, if and else has to be connected because else is used to execute whatever that is does not meet the conditions of the `if/elif` statements, like

```
if (condition):
    Program
else:
    Program
```

So if you separate the if block and else block with other things, it will cause an error.

```
if (condition):
    Program
variable = 2
print(“text”)
else: <—— error “where is my if statement?”
    Program
```